# Output of values of a struct via a function with a pointer as a parameter

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I have two structures. A pointer is assigned to one.
Now I would like to output data previously entered via scanf via a function (outputAddress) with a pointer as a parameter.
It works with the variables via the pointer. But how do I do that with the values from the other structure? How can I output this in the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct structPerson
{
char name[30];
char forename[50];
int age;
};

struct structAddress
{
int zip;
char location[35];
char street[40];
int hNumber;
struct structPerson *ptrPerson;
};

void outputAddress(struct structPerson *ptrPerson)
{
printf("\n\nOutput Address: \n");
printf("ptrPerson->name: %s", ptrPerson->name);
printf("\nptrPerson->forename: %s", ptrPerson->forename);
return;
}

int main()
{
struct structPerson person1;
struct structAddress address1;
address1.ptrPerson = &person1;

printf("Location: ");
scanf("%s", &address1.location);
printf("Zip: ");
scanf("%d", &address1.zip);

printf("\nName: ");
scanf("%s", &address1.ptrPerson->name);
printf("Forename: ");
scanf("%s", &address1.ptrPerson->forename);

printf("\nOutput: %d %s %s\n", address1.zip, address1.location, address1.ptrPerson->name);
// strcpy( address1.location, "");
//  printf("structAddress1: %d %s\n", address1.zip, address1.location);


outputAddress(&person1);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You need to write one more function or change the current function adding one more parameter.

Comment: A person and an address are two different things. Why does a function called `outputAddress` accepts a pointer to a person?

Comment: What should the second parameter look like?

Comment: Perhaps format the code to make it more easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data model *structAddress* is associated with a person via the *personPtr* field. As a result, *Address* is a main data struct. If I understand your intention correctly, you want to print info about the person and then his/her address.

For this you need to do a couple of changes. Firstly, you should pass the Address struct to the print function, because it has *all* information available, including the pointer to the person. Secondly, you should access your person information using the pointer: `ptrAddress->ptrPerson-><field>`. Here is an example.

```
void outputAddress(struct structAddress *ptrAddress)
{
printf("\n\nOutput Address: \n");
// use ptrAddress->ptrPreson to accesss person information
printf("ptrPerson->name: %s", ptrAddress->ptrPerson->name);
printf("\nptrPerson->forename: %s", ptrAddress->ptrPerson->forename);

// use ptrAddress-> to access address fields.
printf("\nptrAddress->zip: %d", ptrAddress->zip);
...
return;
}

int main() {
   ...
   outputAddress(&address1); // << use address1 here.
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Serge. You worded the problem better than I did here. And it is exactly the solution that was sought. And thank you for the very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your datamodel is probably broken anyway. The address struct has a pointer to a person, but it often makes more sense to have it the other way around.

Comment: Does it make more sense to have the other way around? Then I think I have the same problem.
But a person has a fixed name but can have multiple addresses. Is it then better to build the other way around?
I would like to step into the object containing the pointer variable via the pointer. Is that possible?

Comment: If a person can have multiple addresses, then how do you know which address to print, given a person? Your `outputAddres` function has a person, so how does it know which address to print?

Comment: @Raymon Chen Thank you for your reply. My problem is how to concatenate the addresses entered via scanf with the ptrPerson pointer so that I can output them in the function.

Comment: The `outputAddress` function should take a `structAddress*` parameter. Otherwise it has no idea which address to output.